# Could a company test and compile the source code in order to create a company specific application?

Tags: contract-development, gnosis-safe

Given that Gnosis safe is no longer developed, is it possible to take their source code and manipulate it in a way that would allow the safe to stay active and retain the ability to move funds in and out of the safe.

Answer (score 1):

> Given that Gnosis safe is no longer developed

It is not true. The project is being developed and maintained. All the code is open source, and you can do whatever with it as long as it doesn't conflict with the license. https://github.com/safe-global

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about overwriting the code on the chain - that is not possible. You are not able to "update" the code at a certain address.

I don't know how Gnosis safe works internally but let's assume there is an owner or admin role, which is able to perform some tasks. If you want to get this role you would either require the private key or the current owner has to pass this role to you.